# How can I write a recursive query in Power Query to traverse up a tree

Tags: powerquery

Newbie question:  I have a table with ID, ParentID, and Type. I want to create two new columns (StrategyID, SubstrategyID) that contains the ID for the row if its Type = 'Strategy' or 'Substrategy'. Otherwise, I want to look at its parent row and return that ID if it matches the Types sought.  If not, repeat and look at the parent of the parent, etc.  I am not getting the syntax for functions in general and recursive functions in particular in PowerQuery.

I've looked at many examples and videos, and found some help, but not specifically for what I am trying to do.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| Existing columns              New Colums                 |
------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | ParentID | Type        | StrategyID | SubstrategyID |
| 1  | 0        | Strategy    | 1          |               |
| 2  | 1        | Substrategy | 1          | 2             |
| 3  | 2        | Feature     | 1          | 2             |
| 4  | 3        | Story       | 1          | 2             |
| 5  | 3        | Story       | 1          | 2             |
| 6  | 1        | Substrategy | 1          | 6             |
| 7  | 6        | Feature     | 1          | 6             |
| 8  | 7        | Story       | 1          | 6             |
| 9  | 7        | Story       | 1          | 6             |
| 10 | 0        | Strategy    | 10         |               |
| 11 | 10       | Substrategy | 10         | 11            |
| 12 | 11       | Feature     | 10         | 11            |
| 13 | 12       | Story       | 10         | 11            |
| 14 | 12       | Story       | 10         | 11            |
| 15 | 12       | Story       | 10         | 11            |
| 16 | 10       | Substrategy | 10         | 16            |
| 17 | 16       | Feature     | 10         | 16            |
| 18 | 17       | Story       | 10         | 16            |
| 19 | 17       | Story       | 10         | 16            |
------------------------------------------------------------
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. Assumes source data in Table1 with 3 columns --"ID", "ParentID" and "Type"

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
ChangedType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"ParentID", type text}}),
ID_List = List.Buffer( ChangedType[ID] ),
ParentID_List = List.Buffer( ChangedType[ParentID] ),
Type_List = List.Buffer( ChangedType[Type] ),

Highest =  (n as text, searchfor as text) as text =>
   let
        Spot = List.PositionOf( ID_List, n ),
        ThisType = Type_List{Spot},
        Parent_ID = ParentID_List{Spot}
     in if Parent_ID = null or ThisType=searchfor then ID_List{Spot} else @Highest(Parent_ID,searchfor),

FinalTable = Table.AddColumn( ChangedType, "StrategyID", each  Highest( [ID],"Strategy" ), type text),
FinalTable2 = Table.AddColumn( FinalTable, "SubstrategyID", each  Highest( [ID],"Substrategy" ), type text),
#"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(FinalTable2, {{"SubstrategyID", null}})
in  #"Replaced Errors"
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I see now that my sample data is a bit too sanitized compared to the real world data.  The actual data will have records of other types interspersed among the types shown, and the data won't necessarily be lined up so nicely (all stories group with their features, features with their substrategies, and substrategies with strategies).  There also may be orphans, such as a story not assigned to a feature.  For these reasons I think each row needs to use the parent ID to look up the type of record of the parent.

Comment: Thank you @horseyride!  That looks very nice.  I've tried it on my sample data and will give it a shot on my actual data set.  I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use PATH and PATHITEM.

Assuming your table is called 'Table'

1. create a new column:

   Path = PATH(Table[ID],Table[ParentID])

Then:

```
StrategyID = PATHITEM(Table[Path],1,1)
SubstrategyID = PATHITEM(Table[Path],2,1)
```