# How can I adapt this Power query recursion to handle multiple Parents in a hierarchy?

Tags: recursion, powerbi, powerquery, hierarchy

I'm trying to adapt the recursion code below, to handle the situation where there can be multiple ParentId for each Id ([This is where I found the code on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58277252/1981088)).

I see that the `List.PositionOf` can take an optional parameter with Occurence. All so that instead of returning the position of the Id in the List, I can return a list of the positions of all the matching Ids.

The problem I have is what to do next.

How can I use this list of positions to get the list of ParentId elements in the ParentID_List corresponding to these positions?  Or is there a better approach?

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
ChangedType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"ParentID", type text}}),
ID_List = List.Buffer( ChangedType[ID] ),
ParentID_List = List.Buffer( ChangedType[ParentID] ),
Type_List = List.Buffer( ChangedType[Type] ),

Highest =  (n as text, searchfor as text) as text =>
   let
        Spot = List.PositionOf( ID_List, n ),
        ThisType = Type_List{Spot},
        Parent_ID = ParentID_List{Spot}
     in if Parent_ID = null or ThisType=searchfor then ID_List{Spot} else @Highest(Parent_ID,searchfor),

FinalTable = Table.AddColumn( ChangedType, "StrategyID", each  Highest( [ID],"Strategy" ), type text),
FinalTable2 = Table.AddColumn( FinalTable, "SubstrategyID", each  Highest( [ID],"Substrategy" ), type text),
#"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(FinalTable2, {{"SubstrategyID", null}})
in  #"Replaced Errors"
```

Comment: How would multiple ParentId for each Id appear in the data?  multiple entries in the ParentID column on a single ID row, or multiple rows for the same ID, with different ParentID on each

Comment: And what would the output look like?

Comment: Whereas your code returns the id of the parent (ancestor?) of type Strategy, I would like instead a List of all the parents of type Strategy.  So in the output, the new column, would just say "List", but when you click on the list you would see the different IDs.

Comment: Although having multiple rows with the same ID and different ParentIDs would be fine also

Comment: The difficulty I'm having is that my PositionOf returns a list (because of Occurrence.All) but I don't know how to get those elements out of the related list using my list of positions.

Comment: show desired before/after code sample please